# django and static css plus js files

Tags: django, django-templates

i did a small app on django and it is using templates. Each tempalate use static files such as css, js and images. all those files in same directory as template.

```
template
    main.html
    support.html
    about.html
    ...

    css
        reset.css
        style.css
        ...

    img
    js
        jquery.js
        main.js
        ...
```

if there is was to configure django development server to load those files without editing html templates files?

i am receiving

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/face/css/960_24_col.css   404 NOT FOUND    127.0.0.1:8000
```

this changes in settings.py didnt help me

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Projects/site/website/face/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('C:/Projects/site/website/face/static',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the contrib app [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). At the bottom of the doc page you'll see how to use it on development server.

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_URL has been defined as '/static/' so all static files will be served from /static.

In other words /face/css/960_24_col.css is incorrect.

This should be /static/face/css/960_24_col.css , assuming the face directory is located at C:/Projects/site/website/face/static/face.

Might I also advise you not to use absolute paths in your settings file. To find out the absolute path of the root of your project use something like:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: it is strange advice do not use absolute paths in settings.py file. becouse according to default comments in settings.py, it is prerefable to use absolute file paths.

Comment: I meant that it's better not to use static absolute path, but dynamic absolute paths. What if you deploy to your production server, that's running on Linux and you develop on windows ? When you are using static aboslute paths (c:\foo\bar) this abviously.won't work on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I serve static files via the Django dev server.

Defined in urls.py:

```
from os import getcwd, path as ospath
...
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'css/([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+.css)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': ospath.join(getcwd(), 'css')}),
    (r'images/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': ospath.join(getcwd(), 'images')}),
    (r'js/([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+.js)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': ospath.join(getcwd(), 'js')})
)
```